# How to run MainActivity during presenting SplashScreen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I could find two methods to implement [splash screen](http://androidexample.com/Splash_screen_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=113&aaid=135):

```
public class MainSplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_splash_screen);

// METHOD 1     

         /****** Create Thread that will sleep for 5 seconds *************/        
        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                    sleep(5*1000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();

//METHOD 2  

        /*
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            // Using handler with postDelayed called runnable run method

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 5*1000); // wait for 5 seconds
        */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

As expected,both methods first show the splash screen for 5 seconds and then start the MainActivity.

In my App, MainActivity is relatively time consuming to initiate. Therefore, what I see in both methods is the splash screen for 5 seconds and then a black display for a few seconds (like when I do not use splash screen) and then the MainActivity.

The question is how can I initiate the MainActivity during presentation of the splash screen.

I tried to define two threads and run simultanously but the result is exactly like when I do not use splash screen.

```
        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5*1000);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        };
        Thread mainTh = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        };
        mainTh.start();
        background.start();
```

Comment: Why don't you initialize your data when the splash starts? You can use a background task for init and when the task has finished you can start the next activity in onPostExecute method.

Comment: Recommend to read this https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_SHOW_TIME = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new BackgroundSplashTask().execute();

    }

    private class BackgroundSplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is more or less the same (splash screen, balck screen mainActivity)

Comment: you can use splash screen two times and second time set layout blank and then use main activity.

Answer (score 2):

Use best practices - [post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd) from Ian Lake. This gives you branded screen while your activity loads all the components.

If you want to freeze your app for 5 seconds - that is not the best idea, but you can do this. Just send post delayed message to a Handler. In Handler you would catch the message and init your activity with setContent, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for switching.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }

            }, 2000);
```